# How to find the JComponent which has focus within a Swing application?

Tags: java, swing

I am having problems to identify where the focus within my application goes to after activating/deactivating or opening/closing some dialogs.

Is there a way to safely get an event down handed down the component hierarchy to be informed when the focus changes and where to?

In a Smalltalk environment for instance, you could for testing reasons just re-implement #requestFocus on Window/SubPane (i.e. JComponent) level and have a debug statement where the focus went.

Can you do something like that in Java or is there a mechanism I am missing?

Comment: Focus goes back to the component that last had focus before the other other window was displayed. Not sure why you think you need to know which component has focus. What problem are you attempting to solve? Maybe you can use a `WindowListner` so you know when a window is activated. Then maybe use the `KeyBoardFocusManager`.

Comment: So I have an InputMap/ActionMap defined for a component.
This works perfect most of the time.
However, I have situations where i.e. the ESC key event is caught _somewhere_ 
meaning that I need to press ESC multiple times to have the application close
and I really would like to know why.
I have a nagging suspicion that Focus goes away from the Component and would like to verify that.
Also, I would like to learn more as to how this works in Swing.
Thank you for pointing out KeyBoardFocusManager, this looks really helpful already.

Comment: *I need to press ESC multiple times to have the application close* Sounds like you are trying to close a frame/dialog by using the escape key. Yes sometimes you need to press escape twice. For example if the combo box drop down is visible the first escape will close the popup and the second the dialog. Check out [Escape Key and Dialog](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/10/17/escape-key-and-dialog/) to see if it works any better.

Comment: @camickr thank you - I will give an update.
Still would like to understand where the events are ending up though.

Comment: Swing uses key bindings for all of its components. So any component that uses the WHEN_IN_FOCUS binding will have priority of a more general binding. Without more specific information about your problem we can't provide any more assistance. Again, if you click on a button to display a dialog and your close the dialog then focus should return to the button. Focus does not randomly change to another component. If you think it is randomly changing then post an [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @camickr thank you this defintely helps - I still get cases where the ESC key is ending up somewhere. From my tests, it appears it is coming from pressing a command on the keyboard, then cancelling it with ESC. or pressing a command key, clicking with the mouse, then escaping out of the state.
So the problem is in my application code somewhere. Getting back to the original question: how can I track what component of an application has focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do with this, but to answer your question you could add a FocusListener to each element. An avriable is then written using the FocusGained function.

```
int focus = 0;
textField1.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
        @Override
    
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            focus = 1;                    
        }
    
        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            
        }
    });

textField2.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
        @Override
    
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            focus = 2;                    
        }
    
        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            
        }
    });
```

Comment: Ah, yes, that is exactly what I was trying to achieve in an easier way. But I did not think about doing it this way at all. Thank you, that will help!

Answer (score 0):

So the appearant culprit was a debug tooltip. Removing these completely and adding Steffi's code for logging have made me sure enough that this is now solved. Thanks to all, I have learned again something new.